# Child component is unable to read props after re-render

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have found a workaround for my current issue but would like to understand why this is happening or a better solution.

I am passing 7 props to a child component. On the first render all the props appear in the console. On the second render 3 props are missing. This causes my module to error saying it cannot find something that does not exist.

Here is my current solution using JSX. Validate if props exists. If so, see if props.data exists. If so, show the content.

My original theory would be nothing would show. However, this.props.data[this.props.cardIndex].character does show how I would like. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated!

Working code:

```
render() {
        /* Variables that will allow the card background to change based off the props passed for the input received during flashcards and quiz. */
        let bgColor = "card-body "
        if( this.props.outcome === null ){
            /* Background color class will remain empty or return to neutral. */
        } else if ( this.props.outcome ) {
            /* Background color for card when correct input is registered */
            bgColor+= "bg-success "
        } else {
            /* Background color for card when incorrect input is registered */
            bgColor+= "bg-warning "
        };

        log("Card has rendered");
        console.log("props: ", this.props);

        // Below will error if used
        // let data= this.props.data[0];
        // console.log(data);
        return (
            <>
            {this.props ? (
                <>
                {this.props.data ? (
                    <>
                    <div className="card text-center">
                        <div className={bgColor}>
                            <h5 className="card-title">{this.props.data[this.props.cardIndex].character}</h5>
                            <input onChange={this.handleOnChange} name="guessInput" type="text" value={this.props.guessInput} />
                            {/* {this.props.show ? (
                                <>
                                </>
                            ):(
                                <>
                                </>
                            )} */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </>
                ):(
                    <>
                    </>
                )}
                </>
            ):(
                <>
                </>
            )}
            </>
        );
    };
```

Console Log:

```
Card has rendered

index.js:51 props:  {guessInput: Array(0), data: Array(49), cardIndex: 0, translation: Array(49), handleChange: ƒ, …}cardIndex: 0data: (49) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
guessInput: []
handleChange: ƒ ()
outcome: null
start: true
translation: (49) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object

index.js:2 Card has rendered

index.js:51 props:  {guessInput: Array(0), start: true, outcome: null, handleChange: ƒ}
guessInput: []
handleChange: ƒ ()
outcome: null
start: true
__proto__: Object

Review.js:27 Review componentDidUpdate
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to do all these checkings. All you need to do is destructuring your variables in a safe manner like this :

```
  const { data } = this.props || {};
  const { show } = data || {};

  return <div>{show}</div>;
```

using this way, You are saying: if data is not provided, the default value for that will be {}. and again if show is not provided, the default will be {}.

Comment: Actually, it means if _this.props_ is undefined, then try destructure from `{}` (so `data` will be undefined too). Also, prefer the nullish coalescing operator over `||` to better express the intent of a fallback option - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: You are right Anson. that is a better solution. so: 
 const { data } = this.props ?? {};
  const { show } = data ?? {};

  return <div>{show}</div>;

Comment: This does seem like a good solution but I cannot seem to get it to function as intended. Show only returns as undefined unless I remove the brackets. If I remove the brackets it will render and log correctly on the first render, but then it errors saying it cannot read the property of 0 of undefined. const { data } = this.props ?? {}; const show = data ?? {}; This will return the data then empty braces on the second render. const { show } = data ?? {}; This I cannot get to return anything other than undefined.

Comment: I was also hoping to find a reason as to why several of the passed props are mysteriously missing on a second page render. If that can be explained and fixed then the error checking would not be entirely necessary.

Comment: Justin you also need to check values before using them in JSX like this : 
{data && <div>{ some expression using data}</div>} 
it will render only when data is provided